# What is the best way to return duplicate values from a list on the same ListView row in the GetView() Method?

Tags: c#, android, listview

I have some data in a list that shows for example the Item Number, Line Number, Quantity, and Pack Size of an order. The problem is that some lines on the order will have the same item number but different quantities, pack sizes or both. For example :

```
Order#  Line#   Item#   Qty    Pack Size
100      1      12345   640     (10@64)
100      1      12345   128     (1@128)
100      2      23124    48     (1@48)
100      3      53425    80     (1@80)
```

Shown above for item 12345 they have ordered a total of 768 pieces but for 640 of those pieces they would like to receive 10 packs containing 64 pieces each and they would like 128 of the pieces in just one pack. When the ListView is created naturally it will create 4 rows, one row for each of the rows in the list. I would like it to only show 3 rows one for each Item# and if there are duplicate items it should add the quantities and combine the pack sizes into one row. I have tried doing something like this trying to force it to do what i wanted but it obviously does not work that well. I am fairly new to Android and ListViews so I am hoping that there is a better way to accomplish this. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
    public class LoadInfoViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<Items>
{
    private List<Items> lItems;
    private Context gContext;
    private string gLoadnStop;
    private string gPacks;
    private decimal gtotal;
    int total;

    public LoadInfoViewAdapter(Context context, List<Items> loadinfo,  string LoadnStop)
    {
        lItems = loadinfo;
        gContext = context;
        gLoadnStop = LoadnStop;

    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return lItems.Count; }
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override Items this[int position]
    {
        get { return lItems[position]; }
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(gContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.LoadInfoItems_Row, null);
        }
        //If the item at the current position is the same as the item in the next position add the qty and combine the packs
        if (lItems[position].ItemNo == lItems[position + 1].ItemNo)
        {
            string itemno = lItems[position].ItemNo;
            int count = 0;
            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtItemNo).Text = lItems[position].ItemNo.Trim();
            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtLineNo).Text = lItems[position].LineNum.Trim();
            foreach (var item in lItems.Where(r => r.ItemNo == itemno))
            {
                if (count == 0)
                {
                    gPacks = lItems[position].Pack.ToString().Trim();
                    gtotal = lItems[position].Qty;
                }
                else
                {
                    gPacks = lItems[position + 1].Pack.ToString().Trim() + ", " + gPacks;
                    gtotal = lItems[position + 1].Qty + gtotal;
                }
                count = +1;
            }
            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtQuantity).Text = gtotal + " (" + gPacks + ") ";
            gtotal = 0;
        }
        //check to see if the current item is was the same as the previous item added.  If so I dont want to create a row for that item.
        else if (lItems[position].ItemNo == lItems[position - 1].ItemNo)
        {
            //Not too sure what would be the best code to go here
        }
        //if it has no duplicate create the row like normal
        else
        {
            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtItemNo).Text = lItems[position].ItemNo.Trim();
            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtLineNo).Text = lItems[position].LineNum.Trim();
            row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtQuantity).Text = lItems[position].Qty.ToString().Trim() + lItems[position].Pack.ToString().Trim();
        }
        return row;
    }
```

I would like it to return something like this :

```
12345  1   768((10@64),(1@128))
23124  2   48(1@48)
53425  3   80(1@80)
```

For whatever reason it will do what i was hoping for the duplicate item numbers but it sometimes duplicates a different item in the list like:

```
12345  1   768((10@64),(1@128))
23124  2   48(1@48)
53425  3   80(1@80)
23124  2   48(1@48)
```

Anyone got any suggestions?

Comment: I could post some code to do it in a windows forms Listview but I'm not sure if it would help. Basically it does what you're doing only it uses a do loop that continuously checks to see if it's out of rows. It removes the row after it combines them and moves the position, or moves the position if the next ones doesn't match. If you think it might help, I could post it as an example instead with the disclaimer that it is not actually intended as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your fundamental issue is that the Items indexer is stating that you have 4 items available, but your desired result is 3 items.

This isn't really a task that you should be solving in your BaseAdapter.  You should be processing the list in advance and reducing to your target 3 items BEFORE passing it into your base adapter.

Also, you should try and avoid using FindViewFromId in GetView, unless the convertView is null.  In order to do this, you can pack the previously identified Views into the Tag property: that's what it's for, see https://blog.xamarin.com/creating-highly-performant-smooth-scrolling-android-listviews/

If you really want to do it all in your base adapter, then convert the items in the constructor, something like this:

```
public class LoadInfoViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<Items>
{
    private List<CondensedItems> cItems;
    private Context gContext;

    public LoadInfoViewAdapter(Context context, List<Items> loadinfo,  string LoadnStop)
    {        
        gContext = context;
        gLoadnStop = LoadnStop;

        // Get all of the unique item numbers.
        var uniqueItemNos = loadInfo.Select(x => x.ItemNo).Distinct();

        cItems = new List<CondensedItem>();

        foreach(string uniqueItem in uniqueItemNos)
        {
            // Gets all of the items with the target itemNo.  If you want to avoid merging them all, you need to do some work checking for sequential indexes or something similar.
            var matchingItems = loadInfo.Select(x => x.ItemNo == uniqueItem).ToList();
            var lineNo = matchingItems[0].LineNo;
            var qty = matchingItems.Sum(x => x.Qty).ToString();

            StringBuilder packsSB = new StringBuilder();

            foreach(var item in matchingItems)
            {
                packs.Append(item.Pack + ",");
            }

            string packs = packsSB.ToString().Trim(',');

            cItems.Add(
                new CondensedItem 
                {
                    ItemNo = uniqueItem,
                    LineNo = lineNo,
                    Packs = $"{qty}({packs})"
                });  
        }       
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return cItems.Count; }
    }
    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }
    public override Items this[int position]
    {
        get { return cItems[position]; }
    }
    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View row = convertView;
        CondensedViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (row == null)
        {
            row = LayoutInflater.From(gContext).Inflate(Resource.Layout.LoadInfoItems_Row, null);

            viewHolder = new CondensedViewHolder 
            {
                ItemView = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtItemNo),
                LineView = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtLineNo),
                PacksView = row.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtQuantity)
            }

            row.Tag = viewHolder;
        }
        else
        {
            viewHolder = row.Tag as CondensedViewHolder;
        }

        viewHolder.ItemView.Text = cItems[position].ItemNo;
        viewHolder.LineView.Text = cItems[position].LineNo;
        viewHolder.PacksView.Text = cItems[position].Packs;

        return row;
    }

    private class CondensedItem
    {
        string ItemNo { get; set; }
        string LineNo { get; set; }
        string Packs { get; set; }
    }   

    private class CondensedViewHolder : Java.Lang.Object
    {
        public TextView ItemView { get; set; }
        public TextView LineView { get; set; }
        public TextView PacksView { get; set; }
    }
}
```